# error while open rails console or while doing rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

[image]

I'm getting this error , able to do bundle install sucessfully.
Note- Application uses ruby.2.2.0 and rails 4.2

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the gem `uniform_notifier` (1.12.0) use [Here Documents](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) with a squiggly line. This feature is introduced in Ruby 2.3.0. This means that you have to upgrade your Ruby version, or downgrade the `uniform_notifier` gem.